# spark: explanation of Row getDouble method

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using getDouble(0) where the value at index 0 is "2". My assumption was that the string would be cast to Double but I am getting a String cannot be cast to Double error. How is getDouble supposed to be used if not to cast the value at an index to Double? What is the preferred way -- `getString(0).toDouble`?

Comment: Note that `toDouble` is not a cast; `asInstanceOf[Double]` is (and a `String` can never be cast to `Double`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `2` as a `String` in that field instead of `Double`:

```
val df = Seq((2.0, "2")).toDF("A", "B")
// df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [A: double, B: string]
```

This gives error, since the second element in the row is a string:

```
df.first().getDouble(1)
// java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
//  at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToDouble(BoxesRunTime.java:114)
//  at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.getDouble(Row.scala:242)
//  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.getDouble(rows.scala:192)
//  ... 48 elided
```

While this works fine:

```
df.first().getString(1).toDouble
// res4: Double = 2.0
```

Comment: I was confused about the get* methods -- I thought they did casting. Documentation provides no extra info about this.

Comment: They seem to exist to provide a level of type safety instead of type casting.